# How to search by line and replace content for that line

Tags: javascript, jquery

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypusrnc4/1/)**

```
$(".my-item").each(function() {
    var lines = $(this).text().split("\n");
  var k = "";

  $.each(lines, function(n, elem) {
    if (elem.trim().length > 0) {
      if (elem.indexOf('my info1 & test') !== -1) {
        alert("in here");
        debugger;
        elem.replace('959', '600');
        alert(elem);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

As I am searching by line and the condition is met, I would like to replace the text in the DOM but it's not working...

Any help, please...

Comment: `replace()` returns a **new** string as a result.  It does not change the original string.

Comment: I am wondering since I already have all the lines, i can just clear out the `.my-item` and re add them but that might be a bit slow, given i can have 200 of them in a page.

Comment: The impact on the page could be minimized by replacing them all at once, after you have generated all the changes needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/ypusrnc4/10/)**.

You could store the lines in an array variable (`result` in my example) then join them at the end with the new line using `join()` and finally replace them in the DOM :

```
$(this).text(result.join("\n"));
```

```js
$(".my-item").each(function() {
  var lines = $(this).text().split("\n");
  var result = [];

  $.each(lines, function(n, elem) {
    if (elem.trim().length > 0) {
      if (elem.indexOf('my info1 & test') !== -1) {
        elem = elem.replace('959', '600');
      }
    }

    result.push(elem);
  });

  $(this).text(result.join("\n"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<dd class="my-item" style="height: 44px;">
  my info1 &amp; test 959 my info2 &amp; test 1200 my info3 &amp; test 450 my info4 &amp; test 908
</dd>
```